# vba powerpoint chart workbook close

Tags: excel, vba, charts, powerpoint

I developed a macro in vba - updating excel data into powerpoint charts. This was running successfully for the past 6 years. It will copy each selection of data from excel into powerpoint chart workbook and close the chart workbook and go to next chart. But - two days before, after some windows or office updates from microsoft, the powerpoint chart workbook is not closing and gave the error message "close method of workbook failed". I update 1000 charts weekly in average.

The same macro runs successfully in my another laptop, which has the older version of windows 10 with updates switched off.

Any help will greatly appreciated.

Thanks and Regards,
Balu.

Comment: Someone else recently reported the same problem, so it could be a buggy update. Please use the File>Feedback>Send a Frown button to report this to Microsoft.

Comment: It was suggested here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61226735/vba-error-1004-method-close-of-chart-chartdata-workbook-object-failed
to revert to an older version of office 365 to solve this issue until Microsoft fixes the bug.

Answer (score 0):

Try Workbook.quit instead of Workbook.close

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this works: Workbook.Application.Quit

Comment: Thanks Martin. Quit works, but it closes all the excel file opened - including the excel data file from which the data is copied to powerpoint chart excel --- after the first chart itself.